# How to display different components when clicking a button on one page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to display different Components when I click a button with my OnClick in the Render Function of my App.js.

I would like to show a certain component when the button is clicked and it hides the other components.

this is an example of what I want to do

```js
    return (
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <img className={styles.image} src={image} alt="COVID-19" />

      //If the Country Button which is the default is clicked show This 

          <ThemeProvider theme = {theme}>
            <CountryPicker handleCountryChange={this.handleCountryChange} />
            <CountryCards CountryData = {CountryData} CountryYesterdayData = {CountryYesterdayData}/>
            </ThemeProvider>
            <Chart countrydailydata ={countrydailydata} />

    //If the State Button is clicked show this 

    <ThemeProvider theme= {theme}>
            <StatePicker handleStateChange={this.handleStateChange} />
            <StateCards stateData= {stateData} yesterdayStateData = {yesterdayStateData}/>

          </ThemeProvider> 
    //If the City Button is clicked show this 
            <CityPicker handleCityChange={this.handleCityChange}/>
          <CityCard cityData = {cityData}/>
      </div>
    );
```

Comment: You can do this by incorporating state into your app, make it such that the default 'location' state of the App is 'country' and onClick event of one of your buttons, setState to another location, then render your application based on the value of location in the state

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";

import { Button, View } from "react-native";
import styles from "./App.module.css";
import {View} from 'react-native'

import image from "./images/covid1.png";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      state = {

        CityButton: false,
        StateButton: false,
        CountryButton: false
      };
  }

  render() {

    { CountryButton, StateButton, CityButton } = this.state;

    return (
   <view>
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <img className={styles.image} src={image} alt="COVID-19" />

        <Button title="Country Mode" onPress={() => 
           this.setState({CountryButton: true}
           )} />

        <Button title="State Mode" onPress={() => 
           this.setState({StateButton: true}
           )} />

        <Button title="County Mode" onPress={() => 
           this.setState({CityButton: true}
           )} />

        {CountryButton && <div> Hello </div>}

        {StateButton && <div> Hello </div>}

        {CityButton && <div> Hello </div>}
      </div>
</view>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: i am getting the error  that the buttons are not defined

Comment: import { Button } from 'react-native';

Comment: Line 114:22:  'CountryButton' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 120:22:  'StateButton' is not defined    no-undef
  Line 126:22:  'CityButton' is not defined     no-undef  i have imported Button from react-native

Comment: yes, CountryButton, StateButton, CityButton are state variables, which initialize them to false and set them to true when you press the button.

Comment: it is not working for me i will make a sandbox for u to see

Comment: edit the answer, add a <view> ... </view> tag to wrap everything in a node. Do the import {View} from 'react-native'. Test it

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-silence-r0owo?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';




function Statepicker(){
  return(
    <div>Statepicker</div>
  )
}

function Statecards(){
  return(
    <div>Statecards</div>
  )
}

function Countrypicker(){
  return(
    <div>Countrypicker</div>
  )
}

function Countrycards(){
  return(
    <div>Countrycards</div>
  )
}

class ThemeProvider extends React.Component{
  
  constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.state={country:true,states:false}
     
  }

  renderCountryOrState=()=>{
    if(this.state.states){
      return(<React.Fragment>
        <Statepicker/>
        <Statecards/>
      </React.Fragment>)
    }
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Countrypicker/>
        <Countrycards/>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }

  render(){
    return(
       <div>
         <button onClick={(e)=>{this.setState({country:true,states:false})}}>Select country</button>
         <button onClick={(e)=>{this.setState({country:false,states:true})}}>Select state</button>
         {this.renderCountryOrState()}
       </div>
    )
  }

}


function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider/>
  );
}

export default App;
```